# Selenium code to extract text/find only visible elements with "one" class

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having issues with selenium. I want to extract text of a visible element with the class "one".

Here is the html:

```
<div id="result-success" class="text-center displayed"> 
<h3 class="one">Success</h3>        
<p class="two">Yes! I've found them!</p> 
<div class="list-items"> <a href="mailto:ryan.johnson@target.com" title="Click here to directly send an email" class="label label-success three">
```

This is one of 4 possibilities. The other possibilities are not visible, but all have the class "one" in them. So how do I select only this element?

Do I have to use jquery? I want to extract the text within this class, so the text "Success" as well as the email in the "list-items" class.

How do I do this? I don't think the site is written in jquery. My code is currently in python.

This is my code:

```
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("form-search-name")
inputElement.send_keys(leadslist[i][0])
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("form-search-domain")
inputElement.send_keys(leadslist[i][1])
searchbutton = browser.find_element_by_name("search")
searchbutton.click()


wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.one")))
msg=browser.execute_script("$('.one:visible').text()")
print(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to get all `h3` elements with class `one` and *filter the visible one*. Then use the [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) to get the email from the `a` tag located inside the following `div` sibling:

```
h3s = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3.one')
h3 = next(element for element in h3s if element.is_displayed())
a = h3.find_element_by_xpath('following-sibling::div/a')

print h3.text, a.get_attribute('href')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('http://www.voilanorbert.com')
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("form-search-name").send_keys('John Smith')
>>> driver.find_element_by_id("form-search-domain").send_keys('gmail.com')
>>> driver.find_element_by_name("search").click()
>>>
>>> h3s = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3.one')
>>> h3 = next(element for element in h3s if element.is_displayed())
>>> a = h3.find_element_by_xpath('following-sibling::div/a')
>>>
>>> h3.text, a.get_attribute('href')
('SUCCESS', 'mailto:smith.john@gmail.com')
```

Comment: @ohbrobig sorry, but this is not quite informative. What are the symptoms?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):File "/Users/sinaastani/AskNorbert/finder.py", line 31, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.one")))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium-2.45.0-py3.4.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 75, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Here is the website: www.voilanorbert.com. Try it yourself.

Comment: When I try your code without the wait command, I get an error saying that "generator object has no attribute text"

Comment: when I try your code, this is what I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/~~~~/AskNorbert/finder.py", line 33, in <module>
    h3 = next(element for element in h3s if element.is_displayed())
StopIteration

Comment: Very strange...works with firefox but not chrome. Hmm. I don't get it.

Comment: @ohbrobig do you still have that explicit wait?

Comment: @ohbrobig well, you definitely need to use that wait since the search is asynchronous and you need to wait for `h3` element to become visible, or for smth else on the page indicating the end of the search.

Comment: The error came back for whatever reason. Here is exactly what I have: http://pastebin.com/cTe1bnw0raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: It doesn't matter what I set the wait to, whether its 15 or 1000 secs

Answer (score -1):

If you're want to extract text from web element - you must use get_attribute method sending 'textContent'(For Firefox, Google Chrome), or 'innerText'(for IE) parameter. 
I use this at C#, and it works fine.

Answer (score -4):

The following CSS selector should work:

```
.displayed > h3.one
```

*edit:  The question was:

This is one of 4 possibilities. The other possibilities are not visible, but all have the class "one" in them. So how do I select only this element?

The above CSS selector will select the displayed element as only one element parents will have the displyed class.  You can test it with any input criterea with firepath.